# Identifying Microsoft Office temporary files

Tags: ms-office, filesystemwatcher, temporary-files

I'm watching a directory using `FileSystemWatcher`.

When a file is copied into that directory - my watcher grabs it and performs multiple actions with it.

My problem is that when a Microsoft Office file is opened, a temporary file is created in the watched directory. I can't find a way to ignore these files.

Though the temporary file name is well known (i.e. abcd.docx --> ~$cd.docx), I need a better way than this to identify that file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your requirements when you say "I need a better way"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These temporary files are marked as hidden.

Therefore, you can ignore all hidden files.  (Call [`File.GetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx))

Comment: Nice... didn't notice this... 
I'll simply combine both the attributes and the filename test.
Thanks